# ContextMenu won't go away after selection.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, contextmenu

I have the following code that adds a context menu to a textbox on the UI. The user is supposed to be able to bring up the context menu and select a new units to be used. So the method CurrentUnits in my view model is bound to the textbox. I want a context menu populated by all the potential units. So the method Units in my view model returns a string[] of unit options; such as inches, cm, feet, meters, etc.  When the user selects one the method NewUnits_Click is invoked. All works fine, however the contextmenu does not go away when the user selects a menu option. Pressing somewhere else on the screen like the application menu bar will then clear it. Has anyone else seen this problem, or see something wrong with the code below. It seems to have something to do with the ItemTemplate/DataTemplate I have, as creating an set of menu items by hand works fine.

```
    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding CurrentUnits}" TextAlignment="Right">
        <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <toolkit:ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Units}">
                <toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Click="NewUnits_Click" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Tap-event?

Comment: I do not see a Tap event available ?

Comment: What version are you using? This event should be available.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using MVVM when working with WPF, I highly suggest you to start doing so. And even if you are not, I suggest that instead of binding to Click you instead bind on the Command property which wants something that implements ICommand. I think that the behavior you are getting is intended, buttons and menu items in WPF are intended to bind to Commands, it's not just WinForms 2.0.

Another solution would be to hide the Context menu in the code-behind. Perhaps [this resource](http://wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html) will help you in  achieving that.